# Why are there invalid properties in this scss

Tags: css, sass

I'm not able to achieve the following two properties with scss `calc`:

`transform`
`margin-bottom`

Here's my scss:

```
   @for $i from 1 through 12 {
      div:first-child:nth-last-child(#{$i}),
      div:first-child:nth-last-child(#{$i})~div {
        transform: scale(calc(1-(#{$i}*.1)), calc(1-(#{$i}*.1)));
        margin-bottom: calc(20-#{$i})+px;
      }
    }
```

This is my output css for `i=1`:

```
div:first-child:nth-last-child(1),
div:first-child:nth-last-child(1) ~ div {
  transform: scale(calc(1-(1*.1)), calc(1-(1*.1)));
  margin-bottom: calc(20-1)px;
}
```

However I keep getting `invalid property value` for both css properties when inspecting with chrome dev tools. Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have spaces around the math operators (-, +, *, %) and include their unit type.

Your example:

```
transform: scale(calc(1-(1*.1)), calc(1-(1*.1)));
margin-bottom: calc(20-1)px;
```

Correct usage:

```
transform: scale(calc(1 - (1 * .1)), calc(1 - (1 * .1)));
margin-bottom: calc(20px - 1px);
```

Note that this applies to CSS in general, not specific for SCSS.